# WordPress multi domain - redirect

Tags: plugins, multisite

I'm new to WordPress and I have a WordPress site where I've created a landing page that needs to be opened by another domain.

I would like accessing the second domain in the browser's address bar to have the name of the second domain.

That is:

**dominoA.com**/landing-page

**domainB.com** -> ***open*** domainA.com/landing-page

I need the browser's address bar to show **domainB.com**

How can I set this redirect?
There is a reliable procedure, a plugin or other.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that this doesn't have much in common with WP, but...

One of the way to solve this would be to put iframe on page B and set its source to site A. So in site B you do something like this:

```
<html>
  ....
  <body>
     <iframe src="http://dominoA.com/landing-page" style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        Your browser doesn't support iframes
     </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

You could also use CNAME record, I guess...